# Is the subject omitted here?

Tags: passive-voice, subjects

> Then my life fell apart. I divorced, my mother died too young, my son
>   went to jail, I quit my fancy career and, for the first time ever, had
>   enough time and space **forced on me to pay attention**. I started to
>   notice things, listen more carefully. ([Kathy Holwadel](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/15305/))

(i) Is there a subject (*I*) omission, or a null-relativiser before *forced*? 
(ii) Is this ‘forced on me to pay attention’ a type of ‘force something on/upon somebody, to make somebody accept something that they do not want’ ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/force_2))?

Comment: "I" is omitted (*I quit ... and had ...*); and the OALD definition is just what's used here. Note that *had* here is used in the sense of "experienced" ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/have+), 22)

Comment: That deleted "I" isn't before *forced* - it's before *had enough time*. And OP's highlighting suggests he hasn't parsed the sentence properly. What was *forced on me* was ***time and space***. The *paying attention* bit is just something that happened (albeit as a direct consequence of being "forced" to experience all that time and space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a colloquially awkward sentence. The rough sense is quite clear to a native speaker, who slides past the awkwardness, but there's just enough left out to make it very difficult for a NNS to parse.

As you discerned, the subject of the last part is omitted because it repeats the *I* in *I quit*. But as FumbleFingers points out, the verb of which that omitted *I* is the subject is not *forced* but *had*. So the independent clause we're dealing with is

> I had had enough time and space forced on me to pay attention.

I suspect you were trying to read *forced* as somehow governing *to pay attention*, but this is not the case—*quite*. There are two propositions here:

> **1.** I had time and space forced upon me.
>   **2.** There was enough time and space to pay attention.

But #2 **isn't English**. That construction implies that it was *time and space* which paid attention, which is nonsensical. There's something missing; the author means either

> **2a.** There was enough time and space [for me] to pay attention [to] ... *or*
>   **2b.** There was enough time and space to [make me] pay attention.

I'm virtually certain that the author meant **2b.** And that leads me to suspect that she committed the "inverse" of the mistake I suggested that you might be making. She was sitting there composing her sentence and right there on her page (or screen) were the words "forced <sub><sup>on</sup></sub> me" ... and she finished her sentence under the impression that she had ***already written*** the equivalent of "make me".

That's just a guess, of course. But that's a sort of mistake that's often made in speech, and I know it's a sort of mistake I make when I'm writing. When you're speaking, or writing under time pressure, you're not focusing on what you're saying but on what you're going to say *next*.

And of course it's how people *read*, too. At this writing, 23 people have looked at this without noticing the mistake—including me, because I didn't notice it until I had this answer three-quarters written, and had to go back and rewrite it from the beginning.